# How to keep data object in camel context

Tags: apache-camel

I have create a camel context; this camel context is having 4 routes. These all routes are related to complete a same feed processing operations. Now I have got a requirement to share a database object within the routes.

This object is supposed to be initialized at the time for context creation and should be available for all routes to validate data from.

So far; I have create a `org.apache.camel.StartupListener` and registered with the context. This listener will add some properties to the context. But my requirement does not ends with the only string values. I have to put a object in the context.

What should I do to add this object in the Camel Context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create a normal bean to keep reference to your shared object and get the bean like this in all routes:

```
MyBean myBean=exchange.getContext().getRegistry().lookup("MyBean",MyBean.class);
```

Or directly add your shared object as a bean (if possible)

Comment: How could I directly add your shared object as a bean?

Comment: It depends of the object itself (how it is created, etc) and if you want to add it statically or dynamically. For example static XML configuration would look like: <bean id="MyBean" class="my.package.MyBean " />

Comment: Thanks Sergey; I will create a bean like that; But how this is going to be added in Registry?

Comment: it is part of the context magic, it will add the bean into the registry automatically